# Java stream none match multiple condition

Tags: java, java-8

In a dto to bean conversion,

I try to add dto only if dto is not found in the bean... or if the id of the dto is null

I use stream with none match.

When i try to add many car, only the first one is added

```
 List<Car> cars = bean.getCar();
 List<CarDto> carsDto = dto.getCar();

 for (CarDto carDto : carsDto) {

     if (cars.stream().noneMatch(e -> Objects.equals(e.getId(), carDto.getId()) || carDto.getId()==null )) {

        //get car from bd....

        bean.addCar(car);
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe it is a typo, but you wrote bean.addCar(car) instead of bean.addCar(carDto) (car is the list of cars, so you always add the same thing)

Comment: it was a typo...

Comment: Why are you expecting there will be multiple cars added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having the condition `carDto.getId()==null` within `noneMatch` will prevent you from taking `CarDto` that have null id.

You can change it as

```
if (carDto.getId() == null 
         || cars
             .stream()
             .noneMatch(e -> Objects.equals(e.getId(), carDto.getId())))
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Holger@ for this suggestion: You can simplify the second `if` condition as (and need not use `Objects.equals` since `carDto.getId` cannot be null.

```
cars.stream()
    .map(Car::getId)
    .noneMatch(carDto.getId()::equals)
```

Comment: There is no need for `Objects.equals` when you have already proven that `carDto.getId()` is not `null`: `if(carDto.getId() == null || cars.stream().noneMatch(e -> carDto.getId().equals(e.getId()))) …`

Comment: @Holger Yes. I agree. Just copied statement from OP. Not going to make a much difference (apart from an extra `if` check)

Comment: You could use `cars .stream() .map(Car::getId) .noneMatch(carDto.getId()::equals)` when you know that `carDto.getId()` is not `null`. But yes, the differences between all variants are tiny.

Comment: @Holger Thanks. I have updated the answer - I like it as there is no need to call an utility method for this

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the stream API fully without resorting to the imperative loop:

```
List<Car> cars = bean.getCar();
List<CarDto> carsDto = dto.getCar();

Set<String> carSet = cars.stream()
       .map(car -> car.getId()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

carsDto.stream()
       .filter(car -> car.getId() == null || !carSet.contains(car.getId()))
       .forEach(bean::addCar);
```

If `Car` is Comparable on `id`, you could also just use the `carSet.contains(car)` and avoid pre-creating the car ID set.